# Finding ID in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment In which I am inflating a navigation drawer. The navigation drawer has it's own fragment. In order to get my current content with the drawer I insert my current fragment view into my drawer after it is inflated. This works, but if I inflate the drawer it is no longer linked to its fragment. How do I inflate a fragment inside a fragment, and still keep it attached to the fragments code?

```
ViewGroup decor = (ViewGroup) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
View child = decor.getChildAt(0);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.log_entry_fragment, container, false);
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)  
        inflater2.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, null);
FrameLayout container2 = (FrameLayout)   drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
container2.addView(child);
```

Comment: Please put more code. Can't say much with this code. What is `child`?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 okay added more context